# How to send list of files to the back-end as Multiple requests Android Retrofit

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit2

Is there anybody tried to send a list of files as multiple requests using Retrofit
I mean I have a list of 100 files and I want to send them all but in the backend, the server is not accept all those many numbers of files because those are large files
Is there anybody tried to send a list as multiple requests like 5 files in each request and how to do that using Retrofit, 
I want an example

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a concept called as **`Multipart file uploading`**. This cannot be done on the APP side alone it should be implemented in the Server as well, this is the most common way multiple photos are backed up to a server. You can tryout a ton of example available online.